# Detecting mac as iBeacon with iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, macos, ibeacon

I'm just tinkering with iBeacons for the first time. I'm using MactsAsBeacon (https://github.com/timd/MactsAsBeacon) to broadcast a beacon using my Macbook.

I'm just a bit confused as to the simplest way to view this iBeacon through my iPhone.

I tried downloading some apps that are supposed to locate iBeacons, but they don't seem to work. What is the fastest, simplest way to pick up my iBeacon broadcast from mac to iPhone? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

A few tips:

1. Make sure that the same ProximityUUID that you have configured into your iBeacon transmitter on your MacBook is configured into the iPhone app detecting them.  I'm the author of [Locate for iBeacon](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/locate-for-ibeacon/id738709014?mt=8), which is free in the AppStore, so I can confirm that it can detect any valid iBeacon if it is configured with its ProximityUUID.  Here's what you should see:

   [image: detection of beacon with locate]
2. Assuming you have iOS 7.1 on your iPhone, you should know that it has a bug that can prevent it from detecting iBeacons when the phone has been on for awhile.  Cycle power to the phone or turn bluetooth off and back on to correct this.
3. Make sure your Mac supports acting as a transmitter.  You must have OSX Mavericks and a computer with Bluetooth 4.0.  To check the latter, go to `About this Mac > More Info > System Report > Hardware > Bluetooth` then you should see LMP Version in the list.  You need to have a version of 0x6 (Bluetooth Core Specification 4.0, e.g. BTLE), otherwise you will need to get a BTLE USB Stick.
4. Make sure you have quit all other apps that use Bluetooth LE.  Knock app, ScanBeacon, other virtual beacon transmitter tools, etc.  And make sure you have Bluetooth turned on *before* starting MactsAsBeacon.  The app doesn't warn you if you don't have it enabled, and if you turn on bluetooth after the app is started, you'll have to restart it to get it to work again.
5. If you try all of the above and they don't work, it's time to try a different transmitter on your Mac.  My company makes a $10 transmitter app called [MacBeacon](http://www.radiusnetworks.com/ibeacon/macbeacon/), and we offer a [free VirtualBox VM](http://developer.radiusnetworks.com/ibeacon/virtual.html) that can also turn your Mac into an iBeacon if you also install the free VirtualBox software.  Both can be detected by Locate for iBeacon or any standard iBeacon detection app.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I actually am using Locate for IB. I'm confused as to to picking up the beacon, is it automatic or do I have add the address? Here's the screenshot of my mac: https://www.dropbox.com/s/5bzw6gmtpw6ogv8/Screenshot%202014-05-17%2021.22.14.png

I added the service UUID address under the iBeacon Transmitter tab but its still not clear to me how to detect this. Thanks

Comment: The UUID in the screenshot, B0702880..., needs to be put into the locate app to make the iBeacon visible.  (iOS does not allow detecting beacons without telling the OS the UUID first.) Make sure the UUID you put into Locate is *exactly* the same as the one in MactsAsBeacon, then tap Locate iBeacons on the main screen.

Comment: I placed the UUID into the app, toggled the "Transmitter" switch and saved. The Mactsasbeacon is also running. My macbook bluetooth version is 0x6 and is mavericks. However, it seems either the app or the beacon is failing, as nothing appears in the "Locate" table. Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: I added one more tip to my answer.  I noticed when I tried to transmit using the tool, it didn't send anything out on my mac because the Knock app was running which also uses Bluetooth LE.  Make sure you close all other apps that might use Bluetooth.  After I did that, it worked with Locate.  I attached a screenshot of what you should see.

Comment: Thanks for Point 2. I lost almost 2 days of work because of this bug. i was going crazy. btw. greate command line tool